# Can the TO_CHAR in ORACLE HAVE (TO_CHAR(04-28-2017, 'yyyy')) INSTEAD OF Passing a Column name as TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd')

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In general, we pass a column name to the TO_CHAR CLause as `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd')`.

I want to know whether can we pass a date in the place of column name as `(TO_CHAR(04-28-2017, 'yyyy'))`

Comment: Read the Oracle docs http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions.htm#SQLRF006, they will tell you what the parameter datatypes are for all builtin functions.

Comment: `04-28-2017` is not a date. That's a number: `4 minus 8 minus 2017`

Comment: Seriously, are you asking Stack Overflow for the syntax of [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't because `TO_CHAR` function expects either number or date/time value as it's parameter. This can be tested easily.

```
SQL> select to_char('12-04-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;
select to_char('12-04-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

You need to convert the string to date.

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date('12-04-2017','DD-MM-YYYY'),'YYYY') from dual;

TO_C
----
2017
```

OR

```
SQL> select to_char(date '2017-04-12','YYYY') from dual;

TO_C
----
2017
```

Comment: Or using ANSI date literals: `to_char(date '2017-04-12', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`